# groupoids representing mapping stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, simplicial-presheaves

1)Let $X$ be a differentiable stack ((2,1) sheaf over the category of smooth manifolds $Man$) and that is geometric. Let $N\in Man$, then
$$
Map(y(N),X)
$$
is again a differentiable stack ($y$ is the Yoneda embedding). Assume that $X$ is represented by the Lie groupoid $(M_{0}, M_{1}, s,t)$. How to find a "good" Lie groupoid that represents $Map(y(N),X)$ (i.e., something that depend by $N, M_{0}, M_{1}, s$ and $t$)?

2) Assume that $X$ is a sheaves of simplicial sets over $Man$. If $X$ is $n$-geometric, then so is $Map(y(N),X)$. How to find a $n$-Lie groupoid that represents $Map(y(N),X)$?

Edit: As Dimitri Pavlov pointed out, it is not clear what does it means representability here. I'm looking for a simplicial possibly $\infty$ dimensional manifold (or simplicial diffeological space) $Z_{\bullet}$ such that

a) $y(Z_{\bullet})$ is a simplicial presheaf

b) the stackification of $y(Z_{\bullet})$ is weak equivalent to $Map(y(N),X)$

(hence for the case 1) I looking for a 2-truncated simplicial possibly $\infty$ dimensional manifold (or simplicial diffeological space) $Z_{\bullet}$, that enjoys the above properties.)

Comment: These mapping stacks are infinite dimensional (e.g., if N=S^1, X=S^1, you get the smooth loop space of S^1), so what do you mean when you say “a Lie groupoid that presents”?  Do you allow infinite-dimensional Lie groupoids?

Comment: Yes. But in order to have "representability", should I add this objects to $MAN$? By representability I mean the following: it is an infinite dimensional Lie groupoid (hence it defines a presheaves on simplicial sets) where stackifickation is equal to $Man (y(N), X)$

Comment: By representability I mean the following: it is an infinite dimensional Lie groupoid (hence it defines a presheaves  on $Man$ of simplicial sets) where stackifickation is equal to $Man (y(N), X)$

Comment: If you literally want the mapping stack to be a quotient of objects contained in the image of the Yoneda embedding, then the site Man must be drastically expanded.  But in most applications (I'm not sure what your case is though) this is not necessary.

Comment: In the newly edited version, the answer is almost trivial: start with an n-geometric stack X, present it as an n-truncated simplicial object in representables (i.e., manifolds), then apply the internal hom functor Hom(y(N),−) componentwise.  The result is an n-truncated simplicial object in sheaves of sets, whose components are infinite-dimensional manifolds, which present the derived internal hom.

Comment: Ok, My question actually start after a read of the following paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110207. I want to find the correct notion of loop space/path space of geometric stack $X$, (hence $N=S^{1}$). Assume that I am in the situation 1). Using the geometric stacks, I can translate the question in terms of Lie groupoids. So I guess that the candidates that presents $Map(S^{1}, X)$ will coincide with the loop orbifold presented in the above paper (see definition 3.2.1). However your candidate seems to be too trivial. Where is my mystake?

Comment: ups, the definition of the loop space is the 3.2.2

Comment: The above description assumes the target is fibrant.  Lupercio and Uribe do not require the target to be fibrant.  This means that to compute the derived internal hom from S^1 to the target, the target must be fibrantly replaced, which amounts to sheafification.  By Verdier's hypercovering theorem, one can equivalently cover the (representable) source by some cover W, then take the ordinary internal hom from the Čech nerve of W, and finally take the homotopy colimit over all W.  This is what happens in their paper, though without modern tools and language the exposition is rather awkward.

Comment: Let me denote with $G_{\bullet}$ the Lie groupoids representing $X_{\bullet}$.  What you say is that  $hocolim Map(C^{\bullet}(W), G_{\bullet} )$ is a simplicial sheaves (the colimit run over all the admissible covers $W$ of $S^{1}$) and that is weak equivalent to $Map(S^{1}, X_{\bullet} )$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  This is one way to compute the derived internal hom in simplicial (pre)sheaves.

Comment: I wish to thank you for your time. Could you suggest a reference for that? (Verdier hypercovering Theorem)( I guess probably is in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205027)

Comment: The only source that I know of where the Verdier hypercovering theorem is stated _explicitly_ in its full generality is http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03925v3.  See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165302/modern-versions-of-verdiers-hypercovering-theorem/

Comment: Ok, but it seems to me that this theorem works in the local projective model structure (i.e. we localize over all the hypercover). Does this theorem works even in the Cech model structure on (pre)sheaves?

Comment: The site of smooth manifolds is hypercomplete, so the local projective and the Čech projective model structures coincide.